# Computation of integral on set determined by orbits

Tags: probability, lebesgue-integral, dynamical-systems, conditional-probability, ergodic-theory

Let $(W, \mathcal{A}, P, T)$ be an ergodic, invertible dynamical system, where $P$ is a dynamical system, and let $n(w) = \inf \{ j \in \mathbb{N} : T^j w \in K \}$, where $K$ is an event with positive probability. Let $A \in \mathcal{A}$, and for some $w \in K$, set
$$L_w = \{ w' \in K : n(w') = n(w) \textrm{ and } \chi_{A}(T^jw) = \chi_A(T^j w') \textrm{ for all $j = 0, 1, \ldots, n(w) - 1$} \} .$$
In other words, $L = L_w$ consists of all $w' \in K$ with the same return return time as $w$ and whose orbits visit $A$ at the same time as $w$'s does.

This paper I'm reading claims that if $P(L) > 0$, then
$$\frac{P(A \cap L)}{P(L)} = \frac{1}{n} \sum_{j = 0}^{n - 1} \chi_A (T^j w) ,$$
where $n = n(w)$. I'm not sure how to prove this claim. My idea was that if I set $$g = \frac{1}{n} \sum_{j = 0}^{n - 1} \chi_A \circ T^j ,$$
then this is a random variable which is constant on $L$, so $g(w) = \frac{1}{P(L)} \int_L g \mathrm{d} P$. Thus it'd be enough to prove that $\int_L g \mathrm{d} P = P(A \cap L)$. Trouble is that I don't know how to show that. I've figured out that
\begin{align*}
\int_L g \mathrm{d} P & = \frac{1}{n} \sum_{j = 0}^{n - 1} P(L \cap T^{-j} A) ,
\end{align*}
but I don't know how to turn this into the value I want, and am even concerned that I might be on the wrong track. I'd appreciate any help with how to show that $P(A \vert L) = g(w)$.

Comment: Something seems wrong. It seems that $\frac{P(A\cap L)}{P(L)} = \chi_A(w)$. Indeed, if $w' \in L$, then $\chi_A(w) = \chi_A(w')$ (by taking $j=0$).

Comment: @mathworker21 Do you think the above claim is wrong as written?

Comment: that's what i tried to say. do u agree with what i said

Comment: I agree with what you said, though I don't know if this is a matter of me not noticing some detail that makes the identity work anyways.

Comment: no. u cant agree with what i said and agree that the identity works

Comment: @mathworker21 Well I guess there's your answer.

Comment: idk what ur saying. if u dont agree with me, then what do u disagree with? if u agree that the identity does *not* work, then what do u want to do?

Comment: @mathworker21 I agreed that $P( A \cap L ) = \int_L \chi_A \mathrm{d} P$, I’m hopeful that this observation alone doesn’t discredit the stated identity.

Comment: i have no idea what ur saying. bye

Comment: @mathworker21 The identity is about an average of measures. Pointing out that one of the terms of the average matches the value I’m looking for doesn’t mean a priori that the average won’t attain the target value.

Comment: I said $\frac{P(A\cap L)}{P(L)}$ is equal to $\chi_A(w)$, and you seemed to agree. If $n > 1$, then you can just take $A$ to be any set containing $w$ but not $Tw,\dots,T^{n-1}w$. So are you saying that $n = n(w)$ is always $1$???

Comment: @mathworker21 I follow you now.

Comment: i posted an answer

Comment: @mathworker21 I reread the paper and realized my mistake, and might post an answer later answering the corrected question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The claim is false. Indeed, if $w' \in L$, then $\chi_A(w') = \chi_A(w)$, so $\frac{P(A\cap L)}{P(L)} = \chi_A(w)$, and thus as long as $n(w) > 1$, we may take $A$ to be any measurable set containing $w$ but not $Tw$.

Comment: @Aqua lololol i appreciate it